# T-SQL Code to edit XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the XML text below, I want to write an update script to modify the date part `2013-12-30T04:30:00.000+00:00` with `dateadd(minute, 2, getdate())`

1. How do I get the format as represented in the XML text.
2. What would be the best way to concatenate the date?

```xml
<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">2013-12-30T04:30:00.000+00:00</StartDateTime>
  <WeeklyRecurrence xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">
    <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
    <DaysOfWeek>
      <Sunday>true</Sunday>
      <Monday>true</Monday>
      <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>true</Thursday>
      <Friday>true</Friday>
      <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    </DaysOfWeek>
  </WeeklyRecurrence>
</ScheduleDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:-

```
declare @xml varchar(max)

set @xml='<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">2013-12-30T04:30:00.000+00:00</StartDateTime>
    <WeeklyRecurrence xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">
    <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
    <DaysOfWeek>
      <Sunday>true</Sunday>
      <Monday>true</Monday>
      <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>true</Thursday>
      <Friday>true</Friday>
      <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    </DaysOfWeek>
  </WeeklyRecurrence>
</ScheduleDefinition>'

declare @pos int

set @pos=charindex('</StartDateTime>',@xml)

select left(@xml,@pos-30)+
    convert(varchar(23),dateadd(minute,2,sysutcdatetime()),126)+'+00:00'+
    substring(@xml,@pos,datalength(@xml))
```

Returns:-

```
<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">2014-02-19T21:27:36.348+00:00</StartDateTime>
  <WeeklyRecurrence xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">
  <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
  <DaysOfWeek>
    <Sunday>true</Sunday>
    <Monday>true</Monday>
    <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
    <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
    <Thursday>true</Thursday>
    <Friday>true</Friday>
    <Saturday>true</Saturday>
  </DaysOfWeek>
</WeeklyRecurrence>
</ScheduleDefinition>
```

It uses `charindex()` to find a consistent piece of text (`</StartDateTime>`) in your xml.  It then uses `left()` to cut off the start of the xml (truncating off the current date).  It then uses `sysutcdatetime()` to get the current time of your server expressed in UTC time (so that later a consistent timezone offset of `+00:00` can be applied).  It then uses `convert()` with a style of `126` to convert the time into the format required for your xml.  It then uses `substring()` and `datalength()` to add the end of your xml (the length does not need to be exact).

Hopefully, this will give you some ideas about how to go about cutting up your xml to substitute the date that you want.

Answer (score 0):

**DATETIMEOFFSET datatype and XML.modify().**  I would not recommend treating XML as text if there is a way to do it using XML.  Your namespaces make it a little tricky.  This works on SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @NEWVALUE DATETIMEOFFSET

set @XML='<ScheduleDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <StartDateTime xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">2013-12-30T04:30:00.000+00:00</StartDateTime>
    <WeeklyRecurrence xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices">
    <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
    <DaysOfWeek>
      <Sunday>true</Sunday>
      <Monday>true</Monday>
      <Tuesday>true</Tuesday>
      <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
      <Thursday>true</Thursday>
      <Friday>true</Friday>
      <Saturday>true</Saturday>
    </DaysOfWeek>
  </WeeklyRecurrence>
</ScheduleDefinition>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices' AS X)
SELECT @NEWVALUE = TableAlias.FieldAlias.value('(X:StartDateTime/text())[1]', 'DATETIMEOFFSET') FROM @XML.nodes('//ScheduleDefinition') AS TableAlias(FieldAlias)

SET @NEWVALUE = DATEADD(MINUTE,2,@NEWVALUE)
DECLARE @FORMAT VARCHAR(max) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@NEWVALUE,126)

SET @XML.modify('
             declare namespace x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/03/15/reporting/reportingservices";
             replace value of (/ScheduleDefinition/x:StartDateTime[1]/text())[1]
             with sql:variable("@FORMAT")
             ')
SELECT @XML
```